# segmentation fault while using gsl_rng_uniform

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gsl

I'm writing a program that uses the GSL's random number generator, and I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to pass an instance of the random number generator to a function. Here is my source code:

```
int main(void)
{
    gsl_rng *r;
    int deck[52];
    int count = 0;

    r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
    gsl_rng_set(r, time(NULL));

    // Initialize a custom deck 
    // code omitted...    
    // Perform trials
    for (int j = 0; j < NUMTRIALS; j++) {
        shuffle_two(r, deck);
        if (deck[NUMCARDS-1] + deck[NUMCARDS-2] == 11)
            count++;
    }

    // Report result
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << count/static_cast<double>(NUMTRIALS);
    cout << endl;

    gsl_rng_free(r);
}

void shuffle_two(gsl_rng* r, int deck[])
{
    double u;
    int bottom, random;
    int temp_card;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        u = gsl_rng_uniform(r);
        //code for shuffling goes here
    }
}
```

Evidently the value of r is changing while the algorithm is running. When I do a backtrace, I get r as sometimes null, sometimes 0xa. I'm not sure why. I think it might have something to do with the const pointer argument to the [gsl_rng_uniform function, as documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator.html).

Here is the output of the debugger:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
gsl_rng_uniform (r=0x0) at ../gsl/gsl_rng.h:167
167 ../gsl/gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory.
    in ../gsl/gsl_rng.h
(gdb) backtrace
#0  gsl_rng_uniform (r=0x0) at ../gsl/gsl_rng.h:167
#1  0x0000000000400d97 in shuffle_two (r=0x0, deck=0x7fffffffdfd0)
    at blackjack.cpp:55
#2  0x0000000000400cad in main () at blackjack.cpp:33
(gdb)
```

Comment: You're using C++, which comes with a mersenne twister PRNG in its standard library -- why are you using a C library to accomplish the same? In any case, no, the value of `r` _cannot_ change while the algorithm is running.

Comment: @ildjarn, I was hunting down a reference to exactly which PRNG is implemented in the C++ STL, and I couldn't find anything. Can you point me to a link that documents this?

Comment: C++ comes with multiple PRNG engines (and multiple distributions, orthogonal from those engines), of which mersenne twister is only one. The C++ standard documents this in detail, of course, a close approximation of which is [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (you'll want to look at §26.5 specifically). A more digestable, but less reliable and completely non-normative, "reference" can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: you overwrite memory somewhere in the code not shown.  try valgrind run.

Comment: @Anycorn, you are right. I noticed an off-by-one error in my array reference in the shuffling code.

Comment: @ildjarn, I made two versions of my program, one using GSL, and one using the C++11 random number generator. I did a bit of testing, and the program runs 10x faster using GSL.

Comment: @RobertR : That (meaning the poor C++11 PRNG performance) generally implies you're creating or copying too many engines; you should be creating a single engine (per thread) and reusing it, potentially with different distributions.

Comment: @ildjarn, I'm using a single thread. I defined the following global `variables: mt19937 rng;`
`uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,1);`
and the only thing that gets called multiple times is `dis(rng)` per [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution#Example)

Comment: @RobertR : Ah, that's unfortunate; sounds like a bad QOI issue. :-[